# jquery replace tag with tag text

Tags: jquery, tags, replace

i want to replace tags span.textReplace with the actual html

let say i've got a string dom what looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
    hello world <span id="query1" class="textReplace">Query 1</span><br/>this is a test <span id="query2" class="textReplace">Query 2</span> this is <b>another</b> test <span id="query3" class="textReplace">Query3</span> finished
</div>
```

i want the html of #content to look like this:

hello world Query1
this is a test Query2 this is **another** test Query3 finished.

Comment: What do you mean 'Actual Html'? your html already outputs your desired output, as long as `.textReplace` doesn't have a definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

got it.

```
$("#content span.textReplace").replaceWith(function () { return $(this).text() });
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like:

```
$('span.textReplace').html("actual html");
```

Where is this new HTML source coming from?